# How to populate mobile field with values from phone field

Tags: fields

Is there a simple way to populate one field on a contact, account or lead with another field? There's a system I'm using that allows me to fire a rule for a record that has a value for the "mobile" field, but all my numbers are in the "phone" field. I'd like to be able to add the phone field values to the mobile field (or another similar field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Build a [workflow with field updates](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_defining_field_updates.htm) to update your `mobile` field from your `phone` field (as long as both fields belong to the same SObject),
2. Build a [before insert/update trigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) that copies `phone`'s value to `mobile` field,
3. If `mobile` is a custom field, make it a formula field that references to the `phone` field.

Comment: Do you mind if I put the link to the workflow field update docs into your answer and mention that the trigger be before insert/update? Then I can delete my answer since you got there first :)

Comment: Also, I think option 3 is only an option if mobile is a custom field.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Please, do so! :)
And you're right about #3.

Comment: Thanks! So the only way #3 works is with a custom field? That's disappointing... I was hoping there would be something that simple for standard fields.

Comment: @JeremiahPrummer The point is that you cannot change a standard field type. If you HAVE to use standard fields, yeah, only #1 and #2 will work. Otherwise, consider creating a custom formula field.

Comment: Glad to help! :)